# Has the "xkill" command been replaced or removed entirely in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, xkill

I am curious if the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> `xkill` command has been replaced by something similar, or if it has been removed entirely.

I know we can use other methods to stop processes, I'm just curious.

Comment: It is working fine in my main installation. What do you get when you run xkill in terminal?

Comment: @Kulfy My cursor doesn't change. Nothing seems to happen.

Comment: I mean not in Alt+F2 dialog but in terminal (which is usually launched using Ctrl+Alt+T)

Comment: It works fine then. I didn't know it would work from the terminal.

Comment: It would work fine in terminal. So here I see the problem that you are not able to use xkill from Alt+F2. Right? Can you run other commands? Like what happen if you run `nautilus` in Alt+F2 dialog?

Comment: @Kulfy That runs fine.

Comment: Just a suggestion: bind the `xkill` command to a keyboard shortcut. I have `Super`+`Del` for the purpose. That avoids having to press `Alt`+`F2` and then typing `xkill`. And you can go to http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ and search for `xkill`. You'll see that it's available in Bionic and in Cosmic.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`?

Comment: @Kulfy it is x11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug under x11 in 18.04. I've tried this in at least 3 systems before landing to this conclusion. `xkill` if run in a *"Run Command"* dialog which appears after using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> seems to occasionally don't actually execute the command and return "the cursor" instead of **X** (cross sign). I haven't found a bug report yet and still searching for it.

As of now you can switch to "Wayland" and `xkill` seems to work normally under Wayland. To switch to wayland, click on gear icon and select "Ubuntu on Wayland".

[image]